# bash: unable to trim path with "dirname" - path is a directory

Tags: bash, dirname

According to `dirname --help`, command `dirname /usr/bin/sort`  will output `/usr/bin`

So I tried this:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 rawPath="${1}"
  4 trimmed=dirname $rawPath
  5 echo $trimmed
```

And ran the script:

```
 bash ./trimPath.sh /files/data/swx_i/raw/2020/03
```

Output:

```
./trimPath.sh: line 5: /files/data/swx_i/raw/2020/03: is a directory
```

Is it because I store the path in the variable or something else?

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: `trimmed=dirname $rawPath` does not do what you think it does, you need to assign the output of the command in the variable. `trimmed=$(dirname "$rawPath")` now it is correct. Also https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
trimmed=dirname $rawPath
```

will temporarily set the `trimmed` environment variable to be `dirname` and then try to run `$rawPath`. *That's* what it's complaining about, the fact that you're trying to run the directory.

If you want the output of that command placed in a variable, you're looking at something like:

```
trimmed="$(dirname "$rawPath")"
```